# Trying to display a vertical scroll view centered on the screen

Tags: scrollview, swiftui

The text appears near the top of the screen, not centered in the middle of the screen.  Any idea how to center the content on the screen? [image]

```
    var body : some View {

        VStack {

            ScrollView.init([.vertical]) {

                Text("AAA")
                Text("BBB")
                Text("CCC")
                Text("DDD")
                Text("EEE")

            }
            .border(Color.blue)

        }
        .border(Color.red)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use fixed size as below (it fits size to content)

```
ScrollView([.vertical]) {
    Text("AAA")
    Text("BBB")
    Text("CCC")
    Text("DDD")
    Text("EEE")
}
.fixedSize()
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding Spacers on both sides + Fixing size of scrollView will help. Here is your fixed code.

```
   var body: some View {
    VStack {
         Spacer() // Spacer at the top
        ScrollView([.vertical]) {
            Text("AAA")
            Text("BBB")
            Text("CCC")
            Text("DDD")
            Text("EEE")
        }.border(Color.blue)
        .fixedSize() // Fix size
       Spacer() // Spacer at the bottom.
    }.border(Color.red)
}
```

**OUTPUT** 
[image]

Comment: plus one for fixedSize() but the Spacer() are unnecessary turns out.